# Throttle traffic in Apache based on User-Agent

Tags: apache, user-agent, bots, traffic

We are running Apache (IBM HTTP Server 6.0.2.0) in front of WebSphere 6.0 on linux. We are getting excessive traffic from a specific User-Agent from varying IP addresses.  We do not want to block the User-Agent or IP addresses, but would like to slow them down a bit.

Best scenario for us would be to use out of the box Apache config options to solve the problem.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No native way, but [mod_evasive](http://www.zdziarski.com/projects/mod_evasive/) might serve you well.